# How to detect last visible cell in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am new in iOS development and currently working on UITableView. I want to find last visible cells on the screen of device and cells that are at the bottom of the screen must be of blue color, which should fade to green as the cell is scrolled to the top of the screen.

I have gone through these links

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259475/detect-the-current-top-cell-in-a-uitableview-after-scrolling)
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415007/uitableview-with-one-visible-cell-determine-which-is-most-visible)

But could not get success. Can anyone please provide idea how to detect last cells & cell fade animation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ios uitableview fade bottom cell and top cell as you scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726103/ios-uitableview-fade-bottom-cell-and-top-cell-as-you-scroll)

Answer (score 5):

Get last visible cell:

```
if let lastCell = tableView.visibleCells.last {
    // do something with lastCell
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 3.0, you can used this tableview method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let intTotalrow = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection:indexPath.section)//first get total rows in that section by current indexPath.           
    //get last last row of tablview
    if indexPath.row == intTotalrow - 1{

        // call for last display 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@shallowThought solution will only work if cells are already presented.

But, if you want to know the last cell when cells aren't presented yet and are going to be presented, we can create an extension for `UITableView` as follow:

```
func isLastVisibleCell(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    guard let lastIndexPath = indexPathsForVisibleRows?.last else {
        return false
    }
    return lastIndexPath == indexPath
}
```

This way, you can check `tableView.isLastVisibleCell(...)` multiple times until you have reached actual visible cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, It will work

Initially Declare

```
int firstIndexRow;
int lastIndexRow;
```

Write below code inside of ViewDidLoad()

```
 [myTable reloadData]; //Reload because get visible last cell index row
firstIndexRow = 0;

lastIndexRow = (int)[self.myTable.indexPathsForVisibleRows lastObject].row;

NSLog(@"first : %d",firstIndexRow);
NSLog(@"Bottom : %d",lastIndexRow);


- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{


    NSIndexPath *firstVisibleIndexPath = [[self.myTable indexPathsForVisibleRows] objectAtIndex:0];

    NSIndexPath *lastObject = [self.myTable.indexPathsForVisibleRows lastObject];

    firstIndexRow = (int)firstVisibleIndexPath.row;

    lastIndexRow = (int)lastObject.row;

    NSLog(@"first : %d",firstIndexRow);
    NSLog(@"Bottom : %d",lastIndexRow);

    [myTable reloadData];

}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [myTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if (indexPath.row == firstIndexRow) {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }else if (indexPath.row == lastIndexRow) {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }else{
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text =[namesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}
```